# scrapy : no pictures downloaded when I rename them

Tags: python, scrapy

I used scrapy to get the picture from a Chinese website:https://www.meishij.net/china-food/caixi/

The pictures can be downloaded with a name from SHA1 hash of their URLs.But I want to give the pictures new names with item['image_names'] and put them into different folders according to item['cuisine_names']. When I tried to change the code of pipeline, no pictures were downloaded and a warning occurred: Item contains no images.

What should I do to solve the problem?

the spider document meishijie.py is like this:

```
import scrapy
import re
from ..items import ImgItem

class MeishijieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "meishijie"
    allowed_domains = ["meishij.net"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.meishij.net/china-food/caixi/']


    def parse(self, response):
        cuisine_list=response.xpath('//dl[@class="listnav_dl_style1 w990 clearfix"]//dd/a/@href').extract()
        # extract the link of each cuisine
        #print(len(link_list)) # the amount of the cuicines
        for cuisine_url in cuisine_list:
            #print(cuisine_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(cuisine_url,callback=self.parse_cuisine_img)


    def parse_cuisine_img(self,response):

        item=ImgItem()
        item['image_urls'] = response.xpath('//img[@class="img"]//@src').extract()
        item['image_names'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="c1"]//strong//text()').extract()
        #item['vc'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="c1"]//span//text()').extract()

        #print(len(item['image_urls']))


        # get the url of the next page
        next_link=response.xpath('//div[@class="listtyle1_page"]//a[@class="next"]//@href').extract()
        split_name=re.split('/',next_link[0])
        cuisine=split_name[-2]  # get the name of each cuisine
        item['cuisine_names']=cuisine
        #print(item['cuisine_names'])
        #print(item['image_names'])
        #print(item['image_urls'])
        #print(item['cuisine_names'])


        yield item

        if next_link:
            next_link = next_link[0]
            #print(next_link)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_link,callback=self.parse_cuisine_img)
```

pipelines.py

```
import re
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy import Request
import json
import codecs
import shutil



class JsonWithEncodingPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file=codecs.open('meishijie.json','w',encoding='utf-8')

    def process_item(self,item,spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item),ensure_ascii=False) + '\n'
        self.file.write(line)
        return item

    def spider_closed(self,spider):
        self.file.close()


class ImgPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_request(self,item,info):
        for img_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(img_url,meta={'item':item,'index':item['image_urls'].index(img_url)})



    def item_completed(self,results,item,info):


        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok,x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem('Item contains no images')
        #item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item


    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        item = request.meta['item']  
        index = request.meta['index']  

        folder_name=item['cuisine_names']
        image_guid = item['image_names'][index]

        filename = u'full/{0}/{1}'.format(folder_name,image_guid)
        return filename
```

items.py

```
import scrapy


class ImgItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    cuisine_names = scrapy.Field()
    image_names = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    #vc = scrapy.Field()
    #images=scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'img'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['img.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'img.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'img.pipelines.ImgPipeline': 1,
    'img.pipelines.JsonWithEncodingPipeline':2,
    #'img.pipelines.ImgPipeline':1
}
IMAGES_STORE='.../food-image/pic'
```